# Using the python mysql connector module, how can I see the result message of an insert into statement?

Tags: python, mysql-connector-python

Specifically I'm referring to the results of when I commit an insert statement using this:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection.html

So for example if I have the following (the sql variable here contains an INSERT INTO statement):

```
cursor = cnx.cursor()
cursor.executemany(sql, preload_data)
cnx.commit()
cursor.close()
```

After that cnx.commit() how can I see the results regarding what the number of rows inserted versus the number of rows updated are?

Comment: Are you doing [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)? Is your expected result two numbers, one for the rows that were just inserted, versus a second number of rows which were updated instead?

Comment: Yeah exactly, and I think the exact statement returned to me doesn't need to necessarily say if it updated or not, but if it could at least return to me what I would see in say, manually running the statement in a mysql client itself, which would be a number of rows inserted versus the count of duplicates, that would be all I'm looking for.  Just that message or the values contained in that message that mysql returns is fine.